# Java large inputs and outputs

Tags: java, input

I have been working on a java algorithm and I want to improve it by allowing it to accept and process very large String values.

Could you suggest me any good ways of storing the input/output results. I've been thinking of writing it on a file with the readLine(), writeLine() methods? Is this a good technique ???

Comment: @EduardoDennis You mean [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html). I would not use `StringBuffer` (or `Vector`) in new code. They remain for compatibility with old code.

Comment: Do **not** use `StringBuffer`. If you want to incrementally build up a string, use `StringBuilder`. But that's still all in memory, and I believe the question is about text too long to fit in memory.

Comment: @Andreas ditto!

Comment: one man's "very large" String values are another man's tiny string values.  Say how large.  Ballpark.  Order of magnitude.  The faintest hint will do.  But no hint whatsoever, what can I say, "asking questions to the wind..."

Comment: meant `BufferedReader` so it is not all in memory.

Comment: @EduardoDennis What other Java class with a `readLine()` method did you think OP might be referring to?

Comment: String consisting of 15,000 chars

Comment: @Andreas, Scanner ? There are quite a few actually https://www.google.com/search?q=readLine+site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fdocs.oracle.com%2Fjavase%2F7%2Fdocs%2F&oq=readLine+site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fdocs.oracle.com%2Fjavase%2F7%2Fdocs%2F&aqs=chrome..69i57.4726j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: @EduardoDennis `Scanner` is `nextLine()`, not `readLine()`, but sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to store all your string in a text file (if possible) and use BufferedReader utilities ... 
here is the a link to how its done :

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/bufferedreader_readline.htm

Comment: please accept my apology for my poor english ...